# Does the word after "respective" always need to be a plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, commas

I have some confusion about whether a word after respective should always be a plural.

I have changed a sentence from

1. (a) For aerial A and aerial B the masts were moved within 2 feet of the park boundary, due to a shift in position of each solar panel/recorder unit, and so in these two cases the output cables extend beyond the 100 ft boundary.

to

1. (b) For aerial A and aerial B, the masts were moved within 2 feet of the park boundary due to a shift in position of their respective solar panel/recorder units and, in these two cases, the output cables extend beyond the 100 ft boundary.

(Each aerial is connected to one solar panel/recorder unit, which is mentioned before this sentence)

Also have I used the commas correctly in sentence 1(b) and 2?

2. Only one station, Epsilon, is affected by light pollution due to its distance from the main gate and as a result we exclude it from our analysis.

Comment: "**respective**"" and "**respectively**" can go together with both singular and plural depending on the quantity of nouns.

Comment: @SovereignSun: maybe a little research might have been a good idea before making that comment. "Separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used when enumerating **two or more items or facts** that refer back to a previous statement)" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respectively

Answer (score 2):

In this example, "units" is plural because it refers to more than one unit.  It is possible to have a singular noun after "respective" if one is only referring to one thing. E.g.:

> "Each aerial is connected to its respective recorder unit and solar panel."

Answer (score 0):

The definition for **respective** in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respective) is " Belonging or relating separately to each of **two or more** people or things."

Note the **two or more**: the following noun has to be plural. Respective means that Aerial A belongs to unit A, aerial B belongs to unit B, et cetera. Using respective for one person or thing would be like one hand clapping.